# Change console print color in python 3.8 with ANSI escape codes (Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, visual-studio-code, ansi-escape

I'm trying to print colored code in the python shell with ANSI escape codes.
My code looks like this:

```
print("\033[031m" + "Hello" + "\033[0m")
```

When I run the code in Visual Studio Code it works perfectly fine but if I open it directly in Python 3.8 my output is:`[031mHello[0m`

Comment: try to use this lib: https://pypi.org/project/colorama/

Comment: You have to understand that using escape codes is closely tied to the type of terminal in which you run your code. Obviously, VSCode's terminal supports some codes, and what you call "directly in Python" runs in another terminal.

Answer (score 4):

With Windows try clearing the screen before the print command:

```
import os
os.system("cls")
print("\033[031m" + "Hello" + "\033[0m")
```

Comment: It works, but why?

Answer (score 2):

try to use colorama:

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
print(Style.DIM + 'and in dim text')
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('back to normal now')
```